# JQuery automatically check a checkbox and show dropdown menu

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, checkbox, drop-down-menu

I want to check a check box automatically and show the drop-down menu if certain condition is met.

before i had it like this. But now I want the the checkbox to be automatically be checked and toggle dropdown automatically if the condition is met

```
 = check_box_tag 'recorded', 1, @user.recorded, onClick: "jQuery('#Recording').fadeToggle();"
```

this part of code is what I want to change. I tried this below, it checks the checkbox if that condition is met but does not show the menu if checked.

```
- if @tenant.enable_recording_extensions
  = check_box_tag 'recorded', 1, @user.recorded, checked: "jQuery('#Recording').fadeToggle();"
```

This is the full `if statement`

```
      .panel.panel-primary
        .panel-heading
          - if @tenant.enable_recording_extensions
            = check_box_tag 'recorded', 1, @user.recorded, checked: "jQuery('#Recording').fadeToggle();"
            %strong Enable
          - else
            = check_box_tag 'recorded', 1, @user.recorded, onClick: "jQuery('#Recording').fadeToggle();"
            %strong Enable
```

controller

```
if @tenant.enable_recording_extensions
 @user.recorded = params[:recorded]
 return true
else
 @user.recorded = params[:recorded]
 return false
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check the `check_box_tag`-reference at: [ApiDock](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/check_box_tag)

It seems that `@user.recorded` is `false`.

What should `checked: "jQuery('#Recording').fadeToggle();"` do? This is a complete mess.

Comment: it should enable the dropdown menu once it is checked

Comment: before i had it as `onClick: "jQuery('#Recording').fadeToggle();"`` and that worked fine but now I added an condition to met. I want the checkbox to automatically be checked and to toggle the dropdown menu if the condition is met

Comment: The condition, if the checkbox will be checked is the 3rd parameter in the `check_box_tag`, so `params[:recorded]` is false oder 0.